# how to execute SQL statements in command prompt (CMD)

Tags: sql, sql-server, cmd

how to execute SQL statements in command prompt (CMD),

I'm using SQL Server 2012 in windows 8 OS.

I have tried sqlplus and sqlcmd, both are giving error "

[image]

Comment: is sqlcmd installed and in your search path

Comment: if you find sqlcmd, then you can call it with the directory path. you can see your search paths with set on the prompt, look for Path=

Comment: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/sql-tools/sql-server-sqlcmd-basics/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are looking for the `sqlcmd` utility lets you enter Transact-SQL statements, system procedures, and script files at the command prompt

```
sqlcmd -U myLogin -P myPassword -S MyServerName -d MyDatabaseName 
-Q "query"
```

Refer [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx)

Edit: The OP said The `sqlcmd.exe` file is available in the installation path `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn`

You are executing with `C:\Users>` make the path to `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn` and execute `sqlcmd` or add the `sqlcmd` path `(C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn)` to system `PATH`

Comment: sqlcmd is not working as shown in the pic given above. Is there any other way to use it ?

Comment: the path to the file or bin directory is not in your system

Comment: The `sqlcmd.exe` file is available in the installation path `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn`

Comment: then why you are executing with `C:\Users>` ? make the path to `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn` and execute `sqlcmd` or or add the sqlcmd path `(C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn)` to system PATH