# How to execute sql query from command line tool for SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server-2012

I am new in SQL Server, can somebody help me to execute SQL query from command-line tool in SQL Server?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to execute SQL statements in command prompt (CMD)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20965846/how-to-execute-sql-statements-in-command-prompt-cmd)

Answer (score 0):

use below command prompt query to execute filename.sql using SQLCMD.

```
SQLCMD -d <database-name> -U <User-name> -P <Password> -i filename.sql -o output.txt

-d = Database Name
-U = User Name
-P = Password
-i = Filename.sql
-o = output.txt
-E = Windows Authentication mode if you specify this need to skip -U & -P parameters.
```